# I killed Caesar. Am I missing out on any quests?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

**Warning: Spoilers for Results of Killing Ceasar**

So I've been sent to get the Platinum Chip from Benny, who's supposed to be at the fort.

> I went to Benny's casino and got ambushed by his mobsters, and met up with Yes Man who said he escaped to the fort.

Exiting Benny's casino, a Frumentarii guy says Caesar wants to speak to me.

> I got to the fort in disguise but when I enter Caesar's tent, everyone, including Caesar, trys to kill me. I killed Caesar and got the chip (no sign of Benny or the bunker he's meant to be in?), but I feel like I'm missing out on a whole bunch of quests and story line not getting the chance to talk to Caesar.

I've pissed off the Legion by killing a few of their guys, but is there anyway to work with Caesar? Have I missed an important quest?

Comment: The Frumetarii guy give you an amulet which forgives you of everything that you have done until that moment. So it seems like some kind of bug of the game that they tried to kill you. If you don't do anything bad to the legion troops that it shouldn't be happening. So, as Studoku says, you should reload a previous savegame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you were supposed to be able to work for Caesar, if you wanted. You can even side with him and help him take over New Vegas- working for him is one of the four endings.

When Vulpes (or the guy that replaces him) talks to you in Vegas, two things happen. First, you get given the Mark of Caesar. Second, your negative reputation with the legion is wiped and most of the legion will stop being hostile to you.

As long as you don't do anything else to piss off the legion such as murdering their guys after this or working for the NCR/House, you'll be allowed to travel to Cottonwood Cove and enter The Fort.

The problem was that you disguised yourself before travelling to The Fort. You were supposed to go there with no disguise, be recognised as The Courier and been forced to do some things to gain Caesar's trust. Disguising yourself can, unfortunately, mess up certain quests.

There is only one pardon from the NCR and from Caesar- you receive it after dealing with Benny in The Tops and you are invited to meet with Crocker/Caesar. If you piss off that faction after that, you permanently lock yourself out of working for them and won't be able to get that ending.

The only way to work for Casear now would be to load an earlier save.

Comment: Thanks! I think I know what happened now: After I met the Frumetarii and got the Mark of Caesar I went to Camp Forlorn Hope and did the quest to retrieve the lost supplies. During this quest you get ambushed by some Legion guys. I killed them and got on the Legions bad side again making the legion hostile towards me agin. I guess thats a bit of a bug.

Comment: @MeltingDog I wouldn't call it a bug. If you start murdering legionaries and helping the enemy after they pardon you and invite you to work for them, they don't like you.